# Infinite loading

Tags: html, loading, infinite

I followed a tutorial for infinite loading. I managed this code, but the background just keeps loading again and again. I want to display my content just once. Can anyone help me please? Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function yHandler(){
// Watch video for line by line explanation of the code
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eziREnZPml4
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
if(y >= contentHeight){
    // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
    wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
}
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
 }
 window.onscroll = yHandler;
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
 div#status{position:fixed; font-size:24px;}
 div#wrap{width:800px; margin:0px auto;}
 div.newData{height:1000px; background:#09F; margin:10px 0px;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body> 
 <div id="status">0 | 0</div>
 <div id="wrap"><img src="http://images.bwwstatic.com/tvnetworklogos/1470470F-930B-5791-2D55F77DC33EBA96.jpg"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, you want infinite loading or not? If you're only doing it once, a simple boolean flag would handle this.

Answer (score 0):

by setting the window.onscroll to null you essentially have a "fire once" event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function yHandler(){
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
if(y >= contentHeight){
    // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
    wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
    window.onscroll = null;
}
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
 }
 window.onscroll = yHandler;
</script>
```